# Contour Integration of Definite Integral of Sine and Cosine, 4th order pole

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

There is this problem from Complex Variables (Brown and Churchill) regarding the definite integral of a sine and cosine function. It's supposed to be integrated using residues. I've been trying to solve it for years. Must be a typographical error. But maybe I'm just not smart enough. The integral is
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^23\theta d\theta}{5-4\cos2\theta}.
\end{equation}
Can anyone answer it so I can finally let it go? It says the answer is $\frac{3\pi}{8}$ but I have no idea how to get it.

Comment: It's easier if you first use $\cos^2 3\theta = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos 6\theta)$, then make the substitution $\varphi = 2\theta$, then you get a lower-degree polynomial in the denominator. With or without that preparation, the crucial part is to set $z = e^{i\varphi}$ (resp. $z = e^{i\theta}$) to transform it into an integral of a rational function over the unit circle. Then find the zeros of the denominator (that's easier with a lower-degree denominator), compute the residues in the unit disk, and sum. Would you like to try that recipe now?

Comment: I get a 3rd-order pole at the origin. The equation is then \begin{equation} \frac{i}{4}\oint\frac{z^6+2z^3+1}{z^3(4z^2-10z-4)}dz \end{equation}.

Comment: I haven't done the calculations, so I can't say whether that's right or not. But it looks reasonable. What are the problems going further?

Comment: It's getting the residues at $z=0$. I have to differentiate twice. It doesn't look like the answer is just $\frac{3\pi}{8}$. Do you think it's a typographical error?

Comment: No, it's correct. I did it on paper but I don't have time to write down the solution now. If nobody else does it, I'll do it later.

Comment: Often, it's far more convenient to get the residues from a Laurent expansion than from explicit differentiation. If you look at the terms of the numerator separately, you see that $z^6$ and $z^3$ contribute nothing, because they lead to removable singularities at $0$. What you need is the coefficient of $z^2$ in the Taylor expansion of $\dfrac{1}{4z^2-10z-4}$ - by the way, I think it should more likely be $4z^2-10z+4$. A geometric series expansion - you don't need to go far - is convenient for that.

Comment: Also, don't forget the factor of $2\pi i$ from the residue theorem, that's where the $\pi$ comes from, not from the residues themselves.

Comment: Yes. It's $+4$, thanks. I missed that. I'll try that.

Comment: I can solve this.. do you still need it let me know if you are a regular user here ? I'm new here

Comment: Sure. Thanks, Aman.